# jRuby error - can't modify frozen array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, torque

I keep getting this error in my App, no matter what I try to fix.
"can't modify frozen array"

Any idea what could be possibly wrong here? I am running a jRuby (1.6.2) app on Torquebox  (1.0.1) on my local Ubuntu (10.04) machine. Here is a complete stack trace

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (TypeError) can't modify frozen array
    org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter.doRack(RackFilter.java:118)
    org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:103)
    org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:75)

root cause

org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (TypeError) can't modify frozen array
    org.jruby.RubyArray.concat(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1450)
    #<Class:0x1009c9a44>.Plugin(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/plugin.rb:71)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.instance_exec(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2045)
    rubyjit.run_7761DFB9328DE427D0E75A527B886E70C475D69F.run(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25)
    #<Class:0x1000dfe45>.run_initializers(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50)
    org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602)
    Rails::Initializable.run_initializers(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49)
    Rails::Application.initialize!(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134)
    rubyjit.method_added_79E9152BC344C327B5B6A61AD8A4DB7112D305D2.method_added(classpath:/org/torquebox/rails/core/boot.rb:78)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2059)
    #<Class:0x101305815>.method_missing(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77)
    #<Class:0x1002cf032>.(root)(vfs:/home/Ruby_Projects/Sample-Torquebox-App/config/environment.rb:5)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038)
    rubyjit.require_48BC09453A4C02A82A5E47520814DA9EA3718525.require(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64)
    rubyjit.require_3E6CA858403268171F46C45451765CD50640768C.require(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239)
    rubyjit.load_dependency_04443C3CFAC2D53B173F0FF308908A72BD893CCC.load_dependency(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227)
    rubyjit.require_3E6CA858403268171F46C45451765CD50640768C.require(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239)
    #<Class:0x101f38e01>.(root)(vfs:/home/Ruby_Projects/Sample-Torquebox-App/config/environment.rb:6)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.instance_eval(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2028)
    Rack::Builder.initialize(/home/torquebox-1.0.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46)
    #<Class:0x1002cf032>.(root)(vfs:/home/Ruby_Projects/Sample-Torquebox-App/config.ru:3)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR1 logs.
JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR1
```

Comment: Do you get it when starting up the application or when handling requests?

Comment: I get it while starting up the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the error during startup, chances are big you're actually trying to redefine a frozen array in an initializer (could be as simple as redifining ABBR_DAYNAMES). If the application can run under MRI you could try that, since it gives you verbose warnings about this.

If there's nothing in your initializer, then it might be a gem that you included in your application. Try taking out gems one by one and see what the result is.

Comment: I removed everything from initializers (i.e. from config folder) so it has just one file i.e. environment.rb and I tried to redploy the app to torque again. Now it could not find database.yml so I added database.yml. Redeployed to torque again and ran and this time I faced same issue i.e. "can't modify frozen array". I removed everything from gem file too and then it just has rails 3.0.7 and 'jdbc-mysql' and 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'....still the same error of frozen array. Torque has issues with mysql?

Comment: Hmm MySQL through JDBC should work fine with Torquebox. I +1'd your question, since this seems like a strange issue.

Comment: I even wrote a hello world app and deployed to TorqueBox, and the helloworld app works fine.

Comment: I think i figured it out, actually if you notice the above stack trace it shows issues with Rack....so for my app I removed Rack from the Gemfile and its working now. Basically it doesn't need Rack 1.2.3 but not sure why it poses frozen array error? So the builder.rb file under rack was causing issues and throws error of "frozen array", i removed that file from gem folder and from there I got a clue that Rack itself is posing issues with Torquebox

Comment: Your inputs also helped me to nail down this issue. Thanks Martin